# Error Parsing XML Error in Custom View in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Here I Have extended TransparentCircleView class from View class But I am Unable to use That View In .axml File. 
Giving Error        Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)  FieldStar.Droid E:\Projects\FieldStar\FieldStar.Droid\Resources\layout\activity_home.axml   44

**TransparentCircleView.cs**

```
namespace FieldStar.Droid.Views
{

[Register("FieldStar/Droid/Views/TransparentCircleView")]
public class TransparentCircleView : View
{
    private readonly string DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#ffffff";
    private readonly string DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_COLOR = "#000000";
    private Paint _backgroundPaint, _foregroundPaint;
    public TransparentCircleView(Context context) : base(context)

    {
        Init();
    }

    public TransparentCircleView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public TransparentCircleView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public TransparentCircleView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        Init();

    }

    protected TransparentCircleView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        int radius = -1;
        if (Width < Height)
        {
            radius = (Width - PaddingLeft - PaddingRight) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            radius = (Height - PaddingTop - PaddingBottom) / 2;
        }

        //Background Circle
        canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, Width, Height, _backgroundPaint);

        //Foreground Circle
        canvas.DrawCircle(Width / 2, Height / 2, radius,_foregroundPaint);
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        _backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        _backgroundPaint.AntiAlias = true;
        _backgroundPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        _backgroundPaint.Color = Color.ParseColor(DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);

        //Foreground View
        _foregroundPaint = new Paint();
        _foregroundPaint.AntiAlias = true;
        _foregroundPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        _foregroundPaint.Color = Resources.GetColor(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
    }

    public void SetBackgroundColor(string color)
    {
        _backgroundPaint.Color = Color.ParseColor(color);
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void SetForegroundColor(string color)
    {
        _foregroundPaint.Color = Color.ParseColor(color);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you update the code where you are using this in xml?

Comment: Please upload the xml field where you use this item.

Comment: Here is an article may be worth for reading.(http://syedwasihaider.github.io/blog/2015/07/12/XamarinViews/)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this error is not ensuring that the namespace path to the component is in lowercase. The fact that you said that the error returned is "Error Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) **FieldStar.Droid**" tends to point to this as the problem. Make sure you are referencing the component in xml as follows:

```
<fieldStar.droid.views.TransparentCircleView
.....
.....
/>
```